# Calculate Current Inside the Resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-measurement, multimeter, voltage-measurement, power-measurement

So i have a green LED with the Vdrop: 1.9V ~ 4V, Vforward: 2.2V, two AA battery in total 3V and a resistor which has 300Ω.
I place all the component like this [image: CircuitImage] and star to measure and calculate all the possible values that i get.. and hit somethin that makes me wondering how it ends with the result 609mA on the resistor?
could you guys explain where the 609mA come from? I just bought a  "Practical Electronics For Inventors" and Iam new here..

Answer (score 2):

In order to measure current, the meter should be connected in **series** with the circuit.

You are very fortunate not to have blown the fuse in your meter or completely destroyed the LED. 600mA is probably 20x the rated current of the LED, so it's quite possibly damaged.

The current is being limited by the resistance inside the batteries, the LED and (to a small extent) by the meter resistance.

This is a mistake almost everyone makes once. It's good practice to move the test leads back to the "voltage" terminals and switch the range to a high voltage range (AC or DC) before putting it away, so you don't forget next time.

Answer (score 2):

A current meter is supposed to be placed in series with the circuit under test. By placing the current meter, which is essentially a short, in parallel with the resistor you are effectively shorting out the resistor and there's no more current limit, increasing current and killing the LED.

Comment: I just relized.. thank you!!!!!